# node js npm package installation not completed

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to install node js npm packages, but It start to install and unfortunately freezes. I also try to install angular packages and it doesn't any problem. please help to fix this issue.

node version is 12.13.1;

npm version is 6.12.1;

I tried to install packages this way

```
npm i html-to-xlsx
```

here is a result:
[image: install node js npm package]

another installation result:
[image: install node js npm package]

Comment: Try `npm cache clean`.

Comment: I tried but no result

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands then re-run the command:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
```

And make sure you are in a place with good internet connection. Sometimes this is the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I try it but noting changed ;(

Comment: Does it freezes at the same step every time?

Comment: I see that the error stopped once on express. If you installed `express` globally before and now you install it locally (or vise versa), then you need to uninstall it first, specially if it was installed globally: `npm uninstall express -g`

Answer (score 0):

I found way to fix this issue. I add -g before package name

```
npm install -g html-to-xlsx
```

Everything looks good

[image: node js package installation complated]

After that I enter this path C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules and copy needful module into my working folder